# Google Calendar API - Can I get the "Privacy" field for an Event? i.e. Public/Private/Default - or is this not available

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

Re the Google Calendar API, I can't seem to see the Privacy" field for an Event? i.e. Public/Private/Default.

Is there a way to get the "Privacy" field for an Event? i.e. Public/Private/Default - or is this not available?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get "privacy" field for an Event but you have to filter (public\private) events on your query.

```
query = gdata.calendar.service.CalendarEventQuery('default', 'private', 'full')
feed = calendar_service.CalendarQuery(query)
```

The second parameter of CalendarEventQuery is visibility (private\public)

Have a look to [Event feeds](http://code.google.com/intl/it/apis/calendar/data/1.0/reference.html#Event_feeds) too.

Comment: I really want the event: all events that are not in working hours, plus any in working hours that are marked private

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem as you (i want to hide private busy events), and found no solutions on the web.
`getVisibility()` returns `undefined` on private and public events... i dont know why !

So this is a way to find private events, but it not return an array with 'default | private | full'

`getPrivateCopy()` return an `object` if the event is private, and return `undefined` if not.

So there is my code :

```
var private = entry.getPrivateCopy();
//if the event isn't private
if (!private) {
//doing something
}
```

This is not the best solution because that method doesn't remove the event from feed.
If somebody have a better solution, i'm interested !

Comment: I'll try this out when I get a chance - thanks for providing the info

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Either changing or viewing the privacy of an event works.

```
CalendarEventFeed resultFeed = myService.query(myQuery, CalendarEventFeed.class);

// Goes through all events.
System.out.println("Updating events from " + startTime.toString() + " to " + endTime.toString() + ":\n");
for (int i = 0; i < resultFeed.getEntries().size(); i++) {
  // Obtains the entry.
  CalendarEventEntry entry = resultFeed.getEntries().get(i);

  // Changes the visibility to private and update the entry.
  //entry.getVisibility().setValue(Visibility.PRIVATE_VALUE);
  //entry.update();

  // Print some information in the output.
  System.out.println("- " + entry.getTitle().getPlainText() + " -- Visibility is now: " + entry.getVisibility().getValue());
}
```

Uncomment the lines after the "Changes the visibility to private" comment and this code will change all your events to private in your default calendar (assuming `myService` is a properly set up `CalendarService` and `myQuery` is a query that returns all your events).

Hope this helps,
- Vítor Souza

Comment: P.S.: I just found out that sometimes the visibility object is null. If you just want to see its value, check for nulls instead of doing `entry.getVisibility().getValue`. If you want to change it, you can create a new one:

Comment: `Visibility visibility = entry.getVisibility();
if (visibility == null) {
  visibility = new Visibility(Visibility.DEFAULT_VALUE);
  entry.setVisibility(visibility);
}`